# I'm getting error as Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid, butterknife

plz dont mark it as duplicate i didnt find solution is other post

im using butterknife in my proj im getting error as `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

code:-

xml:--

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_terms"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txt_terms"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

activity:-

```
@BindView(R.id.txt_terms)
TextView txtTerms;

   @CallSuper
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_login_activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
            txtTerms.setText("ss1");/////////error crash
```

this is my code

what i have tried :---if i do like this adding this `txtTerms=findViewById(R.id.txt_terms);` it doesnt give error

but what might be error in above code using butterknife

please help thanks in advance

Comment: as [library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) suggest you should use R2 instead of R

Comment: An even better suggestion is to not use this library. It was deprecated over a year ago. Please read the opening paragraph of [the documentation](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#butter-knife): "**Attention**: This tool is now deprecated. Please switch to [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding). Existing versions will continue to work, obviously, but only critical bug fixes for integration with AGP will be considered. Feature development and general bug fixes have stopped."

Comment: If it's a new project , please don't use bufferknife as it's deprecated for a long time now, please switch to [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Comment: Attach gradle file please